# Add content to DOM elements added later w/o JavaScript

Tags: html, css, dom

Is there a way to have same content (inner text/html) to DOM elements with a specific class that are added later.

Take the example of CSS:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If a DOM element is added in future with a class `.red`, it's background color will be red.

Can I use a similar technique for the content of the DOM element. Say, all elements with a class of `data-amount` should have content `40`. So if any element has this class, even if added later in the DOM, should show the content 40:

```
<div class="data-amount"></div>
```

Is this possible without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS pseudo-element `::before`:

```
.data-amount::before {
    content: '40';
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I wanted to also note that using data-* as a naming scheme for classes might be a bit confusing, since HTML elements can have attributes named data-*. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Just what I was about to post. The only caveat to this is that you should be aware this isn't changing the element's "content" itself - it'll display it as requested, but it may have technical implications if you expect to retrieve that "40" later, or try to change the div's content (it will read "40my new text")

Comment: Looks like a good thing, just a question. Can I use the value of the `content` property from some other element's attribute? I mean, instead of hard coding `40`, can I read from an already existing DOM element?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - not without JS. CSS can't look up DOM elements inside attribute blocks.

Comment: CSS can look up element's own attribute though, right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Examples

Comment: @KingJulian Interesting, I didn't know that. Still, not useful for outside elements.